# Detect api changes flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Right now the app will need to detect whether a field from API got change or not

for example the api will return

```
{
 successOrNot : false
}
```

when the field successOrNot become true, only then it will go to next page.

However the method that im doing right now is by using Timer.periodic, so it will call the api every 1 seconds, until the successOrNot become true then it will stop calling it. Is there another way on doing this since im afraid that it will affect the server because of api calling excessively.

Comment: Did you try to achieve that using state management like provider to update listeners by changenotifier?

Comment: You have to change few things in your backend not in flutter. Use webhooks or event streaming like apache kafka to let the app know about a specific change.

Comment: hmm have you try websocketing it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use webSocket in this situation, sever will send message and client (flutter app) will listen to message from server, your current solution is ping the server by REST several times per minute, it maybe overloads the server in some case, e.g you have a lot of client but server resource is limited.

Link document about webSocket here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/web-sockets

Answer (score 0):

Beside websocket, you can also use SSE (Server Sent Events). But just like websockets, SSE require implementation on both server and client side. And depending on the situation both options may not be viable.